# Avoiding duplication in object- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, javascript-objects

I have the next object:

```
var persons= {};
persons["Matt"].push("A");
persons["Matt"].push("B");
persons["Matt"].push("C");
```

And I want to know if the object contains the element which I try to insert.

E.g:

```
persons["Matt"].push("A"); /* The element A already exist... And I don't want duplicate elements.*/
```

Anybody know one way to make it?

**EDIT WITH MORE DETAILS:**

I have a the next code:

```
function insertIfNotThere(array, item) {
    if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        array.push(item);
    }
}

function EventManager(target) {
    var target = target || window, events = {};
    this.observe = function(eventName, cb) {
        if (events[eventName]){
           insertIfNotThere(events[eventName], cb);
        }else{
           events[eventName] = []; events[eventName].push(cb);
        }
        return target;
    };

    this.fire = function(eventName) {
        if (!events[eventName]) return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < events[eventName].length; i++) {
        events[eventName][i].apply(target, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    };
}
```

I use your method for checking if the element with the content indicated exist. But... It push the element ever... I don't know what's happening...

Comment: `persons = {};` creates an object, not an array.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :) I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first. When you do

```
persons= {};
```

you are creating a global property called `persons` and assigning an empty object to it. You might want a local variable here. So, change it to

```
var persons = {};
```

And then, when you create a new key in the object, by default, the value will be `undefined`. In your case you need to store an array. So, you have to initialize it like this

```
persons['Matt'] = [];
```

and then you can use the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function to find out if the item being added is already there in the array or not (it returns `-1` if the item is not found in the array), like this

```
if (persons['Matt'].indexOf("A") === -1) {
    persons['Matt'].push("A");
}
if (persons['Matt'].indexOf("B") === -1) {
    persons['Matt'].push("B");
}
```

You can create a function to do this

```
function insertIfNotThere(array, item) {
    if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        array.push(item);
    }
}

var persons = {};
persons['Matt'] = [];
insertIfNotThere(persons['Matt'], 'A');
insertIfNotThere(persons['Matt'], 'B');

 // This will be ignored, as `A` is already there in the array
insertIfNotThere(persons['Matt'], 'A');
```

Comment: Thank you very much: my favorite responses are those that, in addition to solving a problem, teach. It has helped me a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to solve one error (related with the primary question) and I can't... Your method doesn't work correctly with my script... You know why? I edited my question with more details... ¡Sorry! T_T

Comment: @MartaFernandez `else events[eventName] = []; events[eventName].push(cb);` should have been `else {events[eventName] = []; events[eventName].push(cb);}`

Comment: Sorry, in my code I have in the way you tell... This isn't the problem... :S Some other explication? (I'm desperate...)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check for the existence of A. If it doesn't exist (is -1), add it to the array:

```
if (persons['Matt'].indexOf('A') === -1) {
  persons['Matt'].push('A');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. I chose the @thefourtheye question because it have a interesting explication. May you see again my question? I edited it with more details... (because your solutions doesn't work with my code :S)